# Authenticate Azure Devops Api call without using a PAT?

Tags: powershell, azure-devops

When using Azure Devops functions such as creating a new Repo or starting a pipeline is there any way to authenticate the user without an Access token through Powershell? The only other solution that I found is Azure CLI though I would prefer to Invoke the web API calls.

Answer (score 7):

Actually, indeed you can auth the Azure DevOps REST API without using a PAT(personal access token), but you could not auth it without any access token. Even if you use the user account to auth, essentially it will generate an access token to auth.

For your requirement, if you want to use powershell to auth the REST API, you could use the script below.

Make sure you have installed the [`Az`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/install-az-ps?view=azps-6.6.0) powershell module, and login with a user account which has the permission in your devops org via `Connect-AzAccount`.

Here is a sample to start the pipeline with [`Runs - Run Pipeline`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/pipelines/runs/run-pipeline?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0). This sample uses the Azure AD access token to auth, please note don't change the `499b84ac-1321-427f-aa17-267ca6975798` in the script, it is the well-known resource id of the DevOps REST API, it works for me.

```
$token = (Get-AzAccessToken -ResourceUrl "499b84ac-1321-427f-aa17-267ca6975798").Token
$URL = 'https://dev.azure.com/orgname/testpro1/_apis/pipelines/52/runs?api-version=6.0-preview.1'
$header = @{
    'Authorization' = 'Bearer ' + $token
    'Content-Type' = 'application/json'
}
$body = @"
  {
    "resources": {
        "repositories": {
            "self": {
                "refName": "refs/heads/main"
            }
        }
    }
  }
"@

Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri $URL -Headers $header -Body $body | ConvertTo-Json
```

[image]

Comment: Awesome.  This allowed me to automatically create release branches across multiple repositories