# Authentication via `az login` for Azure DevOps in custom script

Tags: python, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I'm trying to create a python script to interact with Azure DevOps and I have problem with authentication. I don't want to use PAT. When I try to use `DefaultAzureCredential` from `azure.identity`, I get following error:
'DefaultAzureCredential' object has no attribute 'signed_session'

```py
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential
from azure.devops.connection import Connection

credential = DefaultAzureCredential()
connection = Connection(base_url="https://dev.azure.com/org_name", creds=credential)
core_client = connection.clients.get_core_client()
projects = core_client.get_projects()
```

I found another way. This works but I noticed it is recommended to use `azure.identity` instead of `azure.common.credentials.get_azure_cli_credentials()`.

```py
from azure.common.credentials import get_azure_cli_credentials
from azure.devops.connection import Connection

credential = get_azure_cli_credentials()[0]
connection = Connection(base_url="https://dev.azure.com/org_name", creds=credential)
core_client = connection.clients.get_core_client()
projects = core_client.get_projects()
```

Am I doing something wrong with `azure.identity` or is there a better way?

UPDATE: [get_azure_cli_credentials](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-common/azure.common.credentials?view=azure-python-previous#azure-common-credentials-get-azure-cli-credentials) doesn't work with new version of az cli

> This method is not working for azure-cli-core>=2.21.0 (released in March 2021). It is now recommended to authenticate using https://pypi.org/project/azure-identity/ and AzureCliCredential.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed that in a few places ([az devops CLI extension](https://github.com/search?q=repo%3AAzure%2Fazure-devops-cli-extension%20from%20msrest.authentication%20import&type=code), [Azure SDK for Python](https://github.com/search?q=repo%3AAzure%2Fazure-sdk-for-python%20from%20msrest.authentication%20import&type=code), [az CLI](https://github.com/search?q=repo%3AAzure%2Fazure-cli%20from%20msrest.authentication%20import&type=code)) the [`msrest`](https://github.com/Azure/msrest-for-python) library is used. the library is marked as deprecated, but if it is used by Microsoft, I think it makes sense to use it until the use of DefaultAzureCredential becomes possible with [Azure DevOps SDK](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-devops-python-api). I managed to create a credential object by passing the token to BasicTokenAuthentication from msrest.authentication.

```
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential
from msrest.authentication import BasicTokenAuthentication
from azure.devops.connection import Connection

credential = DefaultAzureCredential()
token = credential.get_token('499b84ac-1321-427f-aa17-267ca6975798/.default')
credentials = BasicTokenAuthentication({'access_token': token.token})
organization_url = 'https://dev.azure.com/myorg'
connection = Connection(base_url=organization_url, creds=credentials)

core_client = connection.clients.get_core_client()
get_projects_response = core_client.get_projects()
if get_projects_response:
    for project in get_projects_response:
        print(project.name)
```

Output:

```
myproject
```

The example from the documentation using PAT also works when PAT is replaced with a token

Answer (score 2):

I have one Azure DevOps organization named **`sridevOpsdemo`** with below projects:

[image]

When I ran same python code as you to list projects, I got **same error**:

```py
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential
from azure.devops.connection import Connection

credential = DefaultAzureCredential()
connection = Connection(base_url="https://dev.azure.com/org_name", creds=credential)
core_client = connection.clients.get_core_client()
projects = core_client.get_projects()
```

**Response:**

[image]

Alternatively, you can generate **Azure AD access token** for DevOps
API if you don't want to use PAT token.

I registered one Azure AD application and granted **consent** to DevOps permission:

[image]

Now, I generated **access token** using username password flow by running below python code:

```py
import msal
import requests

organization_url = "https://dev.azure.com/org_name/"

tenant_id = "tenant_id"
client_id = "app_id"

username = "user@xxxxxxxxxxx.onmicrosoft.com"
password = "xxxxxxxx"

scopes = ["499b84ac-1321-427f-aa17-267ca6975798/.default"]

authority = f"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_id}"

app = msal.PublicClientApplication(client_id=client_id, authority=authority)

result = app.acquire_token_by_username_password(
    username=username,
    password=password,
    scopes=scopes,
)

if "error" in result:
    print(f"Authentication error: {result['error']}")

else:
    access_token = result.get("access_token")
    print(access_token)
```

**Response:**

[image]

To **confirm** that, you can decode the above token by pasting it in [jwt.ms](https://jwt.ms) and check **`aud`** & **`scp`** claims like this:

[image]

You can make call to any **DevOps REST API** query using above access token by modifying `api_url` in the code like below:

```py
import msal
import requests

organization_url = "https://dev.azure.com/org_name/"

tenant_id = "tenant_id"
client_id = "app_id"

username = "user@xxxxxxxxxxx.onmicrosoft.com"
password = "xxxxxxxx"

scopes = ["499b84ac-1321-427f-aa17-267ca6975798/.default"]

authority = f"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_id}"

app = msal.PublicClientApplication(client_id=client_id, authority=authority)

result = app.acquire_token_by_username_password(
    username=username,
    password=password,
    scopes=scopes,
)

if "error" in result:
    print(f"Authentication error: {result['error']}")

else:
    access_token = result.get("access_token")
    print(access_token)
    
    headers = {
        'Authorization': f'Bearer {access_token}'
    }

    # List all projects in organization
    api_url = f"{organization_url}/_apis/projects"
    response = requests.get(api_url, headers=headers)

    if response.status_code == 200:
        projects = response.json()['value']
        print("\nProject Names:")
        for project in projects:
            print(project['name'])
        print()

    else:
        print(f"Failed to retrieve projects. Status Code: {response.status_code}, Message: {response.text}")
```

**Response:**

[image]

**Reference:**
[Authenticate to Azure DevOps without user's DevOps PAT - Stack Overflow by **wade zhou - MSFT**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72304628/authenticate-to-azure-devops-without-users-devops-pat)

Comment: I wanted it to work conveniently in the context of the user, so passing PAT or Service Principal doesn't solve my problem. I once managed to run what I wanted but on older versions of packages, but it would be ideal to find a way that would work on current versions of packages.